# Use variable with HTML string and count number of <tr>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable that stores some HTML:

```
var rows = '<tr><td></td></tr>.....';
```

and I want to use jQuery to count the number of `<tr>` tags there are.  I can do it when it's not in a variable:

```
$('#some-table tr').length
```

but can't using the variable.  I have tried something like this:

```
$(rows)
```

but not sure what to do with it to get the number of `<tr>`s out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery-ify the `rows`, *then* query:

```
var rows = '<tr><td></td></tr>.....';
var numRows = $(rows).filter('tr').length;
```

or...

```
var rows = '<tr><td></td></tr>.....';
var numRows = $('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>').find('tr').length;
// or 
var numRows = $('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>').children().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = rows.match(/<tr>/g); 
alert(count.length);
```

Comment: Missing `.length` perhaps?

Comment: Why is this better than using a tool built expressly for this type of task? And why did you post a second answer rather than editing and undeleting your first one?